# Phaser/PHP dynamic image loading

Tags: javascript, php, captcha, phaser-framework

As described above I have a Phaser (v 2.5.0) Game which allows users to login and register. The backend is php and communication works using json.

I have my "api.php" which handles everything related to the game and my "captcha.php" which is passed something like "?id=ABCD1234" in order to retrieve the challenge from the database.

When running in browser it seems to work normally.

[image: php code & browser]
But when trying to load the image in phaser I'm getting a weird null-property error:

[image: image 2]
I've figured the reason might that I'm generating the image in-memory but couldn't locate the error.

Has someone here had any similar issue or an Idea?

part of the js code:
[image: image 3]

Comment: My guess is that the captcha image isn't fully loaded by the time you try to use it. Is it an option to load the image in the state's `preload()` method? This would ensure it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use normal HTML5 to load the captcha then load the game after if the captcha complited, just generate a cookie for captcha complition.